# MYSQL: I want a query to get less price for group of books in m-to-m relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Whats up guys..
Now, I have database for online bookstore the idea briefly, we have books and every book had by a group of seller with different prices.

[image: ERD]

Now I am trying to get a query when user search in database to get the least price for every result

For example if he typed politics then database searching for all books (from book table) that has politics as a key word and get their IDs and then search in market_book table for the least prices for these book

Like that

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    book_id
FROM
    book
WHERE
    MATCH (book_title) AGAINST ('politics' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

[image: Result from this query]

And After that get these IDs and get the least price for every book with market id

This is my query but it didn't get the desired result

```
SELECT 
    market, book, market_book_price
FROM
    market_book
WHERE
    book IN (SELECT DISTINCT
            book_id
        FROM
            book
        WHERE
            MATCH (book_title) AGAINST ('politics' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE))
GROUP BY book
```

Any help please I want a query to give me the book and market with least price

[image: This query give me that]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT mb.*
FROM (SELECT b.*
      FROM book b
      WHERE MATCH(book_title) AGAINST ('politics' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) > 0
     ) b JOIN
     market_book mb
     ON mb.book_id = b.book_id
WHERE mb.market_book_price = (SELECT MIN(mb2.market_book_price)
                              FROM market_book mb2
                              WHERE mb2.book_id = mb.book_id
                             );
```

This query is structured so the subquery on `book` can use the full text index.  Then, the `JOIN` can use an index on `book_id` (or whatever columns match between the tables).

Finally, to get the minimum price, that can use an index on `market_book(book_id, market_book_price)`.

In MySQL 8+, you can write this as:

```
SELECT mb.*
FROM (SELECT b.*
      FROM book b
      WHERE MATCH(book_title) AGAINST ('politics' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) > 0
     ) b JOIN
     (SELECT mb.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY book_id ORDER BY market_book_price ASC) as seqnum
      FROM market_book mb
     ) mb
     ON mb.book_id = b.book_id
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  In the case of ties, this returns an arbitrary cheapest value.  If you want all of them, use `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: change the mb.book_id  zo mb_book and also mb2.book_id to mb2.book